# Java/Groovy monogodb nested query with both AND and OR

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy

I am having hard time converting the below nested mongodb query with `$and` and `$or` to java/groovy

```
db.personSync.find({
           $and:[
                {$or:[
                     { "name" : { "$regex" : "(?i)^test1" , "$options" : "i"}},
                     { "name" : { "$regex" : "(?i)^dev" , "$options" : "i"}}                                             
                ]},
                { "email" : { "$regex" : "(?i)^test" , "$options" : "i"}}
            ]}
);  
            ]}
);
```

I was able to write code for $or part as below

```
def mongoCritera = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>(); 
mongoCritera.add('name', java.util.regex.Pattern.compile('(?i)^test1`'))
mongoCritera.add('name', java.util.regex.Pattern.compile('(?i)^dev`'))
def query = new BasicDBObject("\$or", mongoCritera);
collection.find(query);
```

But I couldn't accommodate $and logic, can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you wants to write a query fetch 
name should be start from (test1 or dev) case insensitive and email start with test (also case insensitive) ? if yes try this

db.personSync.find({$and:[{name:{"$regex":"^[test|dev]","$options":"i"}},{email:{"$regex":"^test1","$options":"i"}}]})

Answer (score 0):

```
     def andCritera = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>(); 

     def orCritera1= new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>(); 
     orCritera1.add('name', java.util.regex.Pattern.compile('(?i)^test1`'))
     orCritera1.add('name', java.util.regex.Pattern.compile('(?i)^dev`'))
     def orQuery1 = new BasicDBObject("\$or", orCritera1);
     andCritera.add(orQuery1)

     def orCritera2= new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>(); 
     orCritera1.add('email', java.util.regex.Pattern.compile('(?i)^test`'))
     def orQuery2 = new BasicDBObject("\$or", orCritera2);
     andCritera.add(orQuery2)

     def query = new BasicDBObject("\$and", andCritera);

    def cursor = collection.find(query)
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {              
        println 'person '+ cursor.next();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            MongoClient c =  new MongoClient();
            MongoDatabase db = c.getDatabase("test");
            MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("so3");

            ArrayList<Document> andCritera = new ArrayList<Document>(); 

            ArrayList<Document> orCritera1= new ArrayList<Document>(); 
            orCritera1.add(new Document("name", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(?i)^[test1|dev]")));
            Document orQuery1 = new Document("$or", orCritera1);
            andCritera.add(orQuery1);

            andCritera.add(new Document("email", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(?i)^test")));

            Document query = new Document("$and", andCritera);

            ArrayList<Document> docList = new ArrayList<Document>();

           collection.find(query).into(docList);

           for(Document doc:docList){
               System.out.println(doc);
           }
        }

I validated this is working fine :)
```